# unresolved external symbol in c++ with MS visual studio 9

Tags: c++, linux, windows

My code will be similar to the below code:

```
class DMLGroup
{
 public:
  DMLGroup();
 ~DMLGroup();
  void    SetName(string name);
 private:
 string mName; 
 };
void DMLGroup::SetName(string nm){
   mName.assign( nm );
}

int main()
{        
   string api="API_DML"; 
    DMLGroup * dmlGr = new DMLGroup();
    dmlGr->SetName(api.c_str()); //Getting link error with this statement
}
```

I could able to compile the above code but failed to link using MS visual studio 9 on windows 7 32-bit OS.

Note: I am able to compile, link and run successfully on suselinux-x8664 platform. The problem is only with windows

Please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `SetName`? I also doubt you got as far as linking, `class DMLGroup()` certainly shouldn't compile.

Comment: You don't have a definition for the `SetName` function, so this won't link anywhere. It probably won't even compile--parentheses after the class name are invalid syntax. Be sure to copy and paste the *actual* code that you're using.

Comment: Not posted code correctly... just concentrated in posing my problem..sorry

Comment: `DMLGROUP` vs `DMLGroup`, intentional?  If this code is in the same file then you shouldn't be having a linker error (unless it's on `std::string::c_str()`!)

Comment: The first one is type and for the second one yes you guess is correct, this code is **NOT** with in the same file.

Comment: Then your problem is you're not linking the files correctly at link time.  EDIT: Ugh, getting too late over here, I meant you're not INCLUDING the files correctly at link time.  I don't know how VS manages it, but this would be equivalent to not passing ld all of your object files.

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles & links fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

class DMLGroup
{
public:
    DMLGroup() {}
    ~DMLGroup(){}
    void    SetName(std::string name);
private:
    std::string mName; 
};
void DMLGroup::SetName(std::string nm){
    mName.assign( nm );
}

int main()
{        
    std::string api="API_DML"; 
    DMLGroup * dmlGr = new DMLGroup();
    dmlGr->SetName(api.c_str()); //Getting link error with this statement
}
```

What I changed:

- #included stdafx.h because it's VS standard - you can turn it off
- #includes  because it was missing
- decorated every use of string with std:: - because most probably you'll use your class definition in a header file and there you simply don't use "using namespace"
- supplied default implementation for constructor & destructor

That's all. Check what from the above part is missing or supply an example that exposes the problem & supply the linker error message.